# Rust store DB connection globally

Tags: database, rust, unsafe, surrealdb

I want to use surrealdb in my rust code without needing a static mut (unsafe code) and without creating a new connection for everything. For example, using static mut:

```rust
static mut db: Option<Surreal> = None

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
  unsafe {db = Surreal::new("0.0.0.0:8080")}
  unsafe { db.as_ref() }.get("user", "whynotdogie")
  unsafe { db.as_ref() }.create::<User>("nothendev")
}
```

And connecting every time speaks for itself. Is there any way to do this without unsafe code or creating a new connection every time?

I tried with static muts, but i need unsafe, and i tried connecting every time, but i dont think that is very performant and i think it uses a lot of bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not write this code**. It is **highly** unidiomatic and **very** dangerous. If you **need** some globally visible state consider using something like [Once cell](https://crates.io/crates/once_cell). And don't forget to wrap your type in some sort of synchronization primitive such as `Mutex` if you want to mutate it from different threads.

For example:

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;

static GLOBAL_CONNECTION: Lazy<Mutex<Surreal>> = Lazy::new(|| {
    let db = Surreal::new("0.0.0.0:8080");
    Mutex::new(db)
});

fn main() {
    // Use here db
    GLOBAL_CONNECTION.lock().unwrap()...
}
```

This will initialize `GLOBAL_CONNECTION` the first time you use it, and after that you will be able to access it.

However consider simpler and more idiomatic approach to just pass your database connection as a part of your program's state. For example

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let connection = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Surreal::new("0.0.0.0:8080")));

    // pass this to functions that need db connection
}
```

Comment: how would the second example work if its mostly async functions (Tide web server) and the DB needs to be mutable?

Comment: I will work the same as the first example. You lock mutex and get `&mut Surreal`. Although if you want to do this inside async functions I would recommend using `Mutex` from [futures](https://crates.io/crates/futures) crate.